# Result misses a "-" sign

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int \frac{x^{n+2}}{e^{x^2}(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n+1} \int x^{n+2}e^{-x^2}dx \to n+2=u, n+1=u-1 $$ $$ \frac{1}{u-1}\int x^ue^{-x^2}dx \to x^2=k, x=\sqrt{k}, dt=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}dk $$ $$ \frac{1}{2(u-1)}\int k^{u/2}e^{-k}k^{-1/2}dk = \frac{1}{2(u-1)}\int k^{\frac{u-1}{2}}e^{-k}dk = \frac{1}{2(n+1)}\int k^{\frac{n+1}{2}}e^{-k}dk = I $$  $$ \to -\Gamma\biggl(\frac{n+3}{2},k\biggl) = \int_{k}^{\infty} t^{\frac{n+3}{2}-1}e^{-t}dt = \int_{k}^{\infty} t^{\frac{n+1}{2}}e^{-t}dt \to I = -\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\Gamma\biggl(\frac{n+3}{2},x^2\biggl)$$
$$ \to a\int x^ne^{-x^2}dx = a\biggl[\frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{x^2}(n+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)}\Gamma\biggl(\frac{n+3}{2},x^2\biggl)\biggl] $$
Apparently the result should be $$ \to a\int x^ne^{-x^2}dx = a\biggl[\frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{x^2}(n+1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)}\Gamma\biggl(\frac{n+3}{2},x^2\biggl)\biggl] $$ but i can't find any mistakes, if anyone could help it'd be great!

Comment: The fourth line is obviously not true? Compare the first and last expression.

Comment: @prets what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The string of equalities on line 4 implies $2(n+1) = 1$, no?

Comment: I... I don't see it

Comment: Well sure, you just changed an equality to a little arrow.

Comment: Look, I don't see what I did wrong in my calculations: if you could just help i'd be very grateful :)

Comment: **A way to find your error**.  Get some values where the"should be" line differs from your value. For example, $n=0, a=1$.]  Try these values on one of your middle lines, see if it is true.  If true, your error is below that; if false your error is above that.  Continue to narrow it down until you have a single step that goes from true to false.  That is your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Gamma(s, x) = \color{red}{-} x^{s - 1} e^{-x},
$$
not
$$
\color{red}{+} x^{s - 1} e^{-x}
$$
since the variable $x$ is in the lower limit, not the upper limit, of the integral.

Hence the expression for $I$ in the fourth line in terms of the incomplete Gamma function is off by a minus sign.

Comment: thanks. is it correct now?

Comment: Yes it's fine. Of course the final line is now off, since the minus sign should propagate, and then you end up with the same answer as the "should" line.